# Search array keys with wildcard

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have the following array:

```
$arr = array(
   "number2"=>"valid",
   "number13"=>"valid"
);
```

and I need to find if there is a key that exists with `number*`.

For `$arr`, this would be true. For the following array:

```
$arr2 = array(
   "key"=>"foo",
   "key2"=>"foo2"
);
```

this would return false.

Comment: Lots of ways to approach it - a plain old `foreach()` loop appending to an output array, or if you want to be clever, `array_filter()` plus `array_flip()`.

Comment: You can use `array_key_exists` to check for a specific array key, but there isn't a wildcard version available. You can use a loop to check multiple values.

Comment: Or just [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep) on [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one assumes number needs to be followed by an actual number (edit: or nothing at all), adjust the regular expression as necessary.  For example, anything starting with 'number', you could use `/^number/`.

```
if(count(preg_grep('/^number[\d]*/', array_keys($arr))) > 0)
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expression.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  // NOTE: check for the right format of the regular expression 
  if (preg_match("/^number([0-9]*)$", $key)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
  } else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
  }
}
```

Comment: this will work, but like @mario suggested, a `preg_grep` on `array_keys` is simpler and more "programmatic". php has lots and lots of useful array functions to save typing.

Comment: This worked wonderfully for me. I have a table of email recipients and radio options where column 1 is the sender (only one allowed), and column 2 has radio options for "To", "CC", and "NA" for the people in column 3. The values of what's selected is carried in $_POST. On the next page I needed to parse through $_POST and look for the keys starting with "radio" in order to make the person the sender, a "To" recipient, a "CC" recipient, or don't send mail at all ("NA").

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function which will do what you want:

```php
function preg_grep_key($pattern, $input) {
    return preg_grep($pattern, array_keys($input));
}

// ----- Usage -----

$arr = array(
   "number2"=>"valid",
   "number13"=>"valid"
);


if (count(preg_grep_key('/^number/', $arr)) === 0) {
    // Nope
} else {
    // Yep
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EPB and Dan Horrigan got it right, but from code cleanliness perspective, let me leave these here:

If you purely want to return true or false, you don't need an if statement; just return the result of the `empty()` check on the result of `preg_grep()`:

```
return !empty(preg_grep('/^number[\d]*/', array_keys($arr));
```

If you need to run an 'if' check, `count()` or `!empty()` will return truthy/falsy already, you don't need to double-check their value:

```
if ( count( preg_grep('/^number[\d]*/', array_keys( $arr )) ) ) {
   // Action when it is true
} else {
   // Action when it is false
}
```

I personally prefer `empty()` over counting the result array elements, because type consistency:

```
if ( !empty( preg_grep('/^number[\d]*/', array_keys( $arr )) ) ) {
   // Action when it is true
} else {
   // Action when it is false
}
```

More on truthy/falsy, i.e. when a statement evaluates to true/false: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php